# different profile for dependency in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having different.properties files in my project

```
application-dev-a.properties
application-dev-b.properties
```

now, I am having a dependency in my pom.xml that also has different.properties files

```
application-dev-c.properties
application-dev-d.properties
```

how can I, run my project in dev-a profile and dependency in dev-c profile?

Comment: That is not how it works. Just enable both profiles `spring.profiles.active=div-a,dev-c`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Profils and Maven Profiles have nothing in common.

Spring:
"A profile is a named logical grouping that may be activated programmatically" so that iss a runtime thing

Maven:
"Maven profiles can be used to create customized build configurations" so that is a build time thing